# Optimizing Navigation Drawer Speed On Close - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

I want to optimize the speed at which my navigation drawer closes. On my navigation drawer, when i click on an item, it navigates to a different activity but the rate of speed at which the navigation is not very fast ( compared to how it closes when you click outside of the navigation drawer, it closes very smooth).

How do i make the navigation drawer close very smoothly before the new activity shows up?

This is how i close my nav bar to open new activities

```
private void SetUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
        {
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                int id = e.MenuItem.ItemId;
                switch (id)
                {
                    case Resource.Id.nav_1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(activity1));
                        this.StartActivity(intent);
                        GC.Collect();

                        break;

                    case Resource.Id.nav_2:
                        if (user != null)
                        {

                            Intent events = new Intent(this, typeof(EventActivity));
                            this.StartActivity(events);
                            GC.Collect();
                        }
                        else {
                            Intent loginEvent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity));
                            this.StartActivity(loginEvent);
                        }

                        break;   
                }
                e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            };

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delay execution of a chosen action until the drawer is closed. So, once user clicks the navigation item you should remember his choice, close the drawer and only after that process the choice.